# Drawing a graph for the telephone/gossip problem with $n=5$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Gossip Problem: there are n people and each of them knows some item of
> gossip not known to the others. They communicate by telephone and
> whenever one person calls another, they tell each other all that they
> know at that time. How many calls are required before each gossip
> knows everything?

The number of calls for $n=5$ should be $6$. However, I can't seem to find a graph that everyone knows every piece of information in $6$ calls ($n=5$). The smallest amount of calls I seem to find is $7$ calls. Which is the following:
[image: Graph]

What graph reaches the goal in $6$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An optimal sequence that spreads knowledge among $n$ people in $2n-4$ calls if $n\ge4$ works like this: Four “collectors” talk to all other $n-4$ people in $n-4$ calls. Then the four collectors talk among each other pairwise twice, first in one pair partition and then in another, which spreads all their knowledge among them in $4$ calls. Then the collectors make another $n-4$ calls to spread the knowledge among the crowd, for a total of $n-4+4+n-4=2n-4$ calls. In your case, this could be, for instance: $A\leftrightarrow E$ (first phase completed), $A\leftrightarrow B$, $C\leftrightarrow D$ (first pair partition completed), $A\leftrightarrow C$, $B\leftrightarrow D$ (second pair partition and second phase completed), $A\leftrightarrow E$ (third phase completed).